# specific data type from character to numeric in R

Tags: r

Need to convert this character value : 2.41567e-2 into a numeric to be able to do mathematic manipulations with it. (There is a whole column of character values like this that need to be converted into numerics.)

I've changed it from a different class into a string so that it no longer holds additional data in it.

Comment: Try with `as.numeric(df1$col1)`

Comment: vector is atomic so that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as.data.frame.numeric()` function.

Here is a complete example :

```r
# Build sample data frame
x = c('2.41567e-2','2.41567e-2','2.41567e-2'
df = data.frame(x)

# Convert the values to numeric
df$x = as.data.frame.numeric(df$x)

# Check the value type
typeof(df$x[[1]])
```

This returns:

`[1] "integer"`